# Having trouble checking for existing session

Tags: php, session

So I'm making a very rudimentary login system on my website, and I'm having trouble using session_status to check for an active session. Here's how it's going:

I have a registration page which simultaneously acts as a form (when `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'`) and a script to add the user to the database (when `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`). If everything goes well and the user is added, then I execute the following code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;

header('Location: registration-successful.php');
exit();
```

I know that my `session_start()` isn't at the beginning of the code, but that's okay because the program doesn't output anything before `session_start()` is called. (In fact, the only way `session_start()` can be called is if it never outputs anything, since it exits right after.)

My registration-successful.php code looks like this:

```
<?php
    if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
        session_start();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Noether Here Nor There - Registration Successful</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Congratulations <?php echo "{$_SESSION['username']}" ?>, you were successfully registered!</h1>
<p>Continue on to <a href="index.php">the main site</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

As it stands, this code doesn't work. It instead prints out "Congratulations , you were successfully registered." That is, it's not recognizing the `$_SESSION`. So clearly the `session_start()` isn't being executed. So the if statement is failing.

But I don't understand why. In fact, when I remove the `if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)` and simply put `session_start()`, it works.

But I need to be able to use the `session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE` because on my homepage, I use it to determine whether to display a login screen or the user's home page.

Clearly, it's doable - after all, nearly every website (Facebook, for example) is able to display their login page if you're not logged in and display your home page if you are. So they must be checking for an active session somehow. I would use something like `isset($_SESSION[...])`, but

a) I've been told that you can't reference `$_SESSION` variables before declaring `session_start()`, and
b) The session_status function is supposed to eliminate the need for all that hacky stuff.

Will someone please shed some light on this? I think I'm beginning to go mad.

EDIT: Here's the code for my index.php page (which is linked to from registration-successful.php):

```
<?php
    if(session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
    $active = FALSE;
    } else{
        $active = TRUE;
        session_start();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <?php
        if(!$active){
    ?>
        <a href="login.php">Log In</a>
        <br />
        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <?php
        } else {
            echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['username'] . ".";

        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT #2: Thanks guys, problem solved. I misunderstood what session_status was doing and when one would use it.
The updated code simply puts session_start() at the top and then loads the appropriate stuff based on the condition "if(isset($_SESSION['username']))".**

Comment: I think I must not be understanding what session_status is checking. Here's how I think it works: on the register.php page, the session gets created, and the session variables for username and password are initialized. Then, on the next page, session_status() should return PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE since I just created one on the previous page. In other words, I should only do session_start() if the session_status == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE test succeeds, because otherwise, they need to log in. So I don't really get why it shouldn't just be "if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();}".

Comment: _“on the next page, session_status() should return PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE since I just created one on the previous page”_ – no, this is not how it works. You will get PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE only if a session was started already _in the current script_ – otherwise you will get PHP_SESSION_NONE (or PHP_SESSION_DISABLED respectively).

Comment: Oh. That seems a bit dull. So how does one check to see if someone is logged in (i.e. has a session going (from a previous page)) ?

Comment: I found an older discussion here: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=148593 where they say to simply check to see if $_SESSION['username'] is set. Is that still the way to go about it? I guess I've been making this needlessly complicated.

Comment: Yep. That seems to work. Thanks, CBroe. I don't know why it's so hard to find as clear an explanation as you gave. All works now.

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php `I don't know why it's so hard to find as clear an explanation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
<?php
    if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();}
?>
```

OR:

```
<?php
    if(session_status() != 2) {session_start();}
    // your code
?>
```

This option work fine without warning.

```
0 = PHP_SESSION_DISABLED
1 = PHP_SESSION_NONE
2 = PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE
```

Comment: It does make the username show up, but then when I click on the link from registration-successful.php to my index.php page, the session is gone. I'll post the source for index.php as well.

Comment: In index.php page also need to change `if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();} `

Comment: Shouldn't I be using session_start() to resume the session from the previous page? I.e. if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start(); }? What I don't get is that the condition failing seems to indicate that there isn't a session active, but then how am I getting the username variable? If the == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE test fails, shouldn't that mean that there isn't any information in the $_SESSION variable? Or at least that the PHPSESSIONID is null? Sorry if my questions don't make much sense - it's late and I'm a noob to this stuff.

Comment: You need to use `session_start()` when `session_status()!==PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE`

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turned out that your answer wasn't the answer to my problem, but it was the answer to the problem I thought I had. In any case, it was helpful in understand the actual problem, so the answer goes to you.

Answer (score 1):

Chris, I just found out that " if(session_status() != 2) {session_start();} " DOES NOT work, no matter what the PHP documentation says. You must start the session and then check for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
  session_start();    
  if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    session_start();
  }
?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.